# In Linux, how can I intercept keyboard input and optionally filter it?

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-events

I'm writing a cross platform application, I want to be able to intercept keyboard input and optionally filter it from reaching the rest application. My application loads plugins, I am trying to stop the keystrokes from reaching the plugin's UI if it has focus.

On Window I use `SetWindowsHookExA` and on macOS I use `[NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:]`

Is there an equivalent for Linux?

Comment: X11 doesn't have a concept of application. Nothing prevents your plugin from running its own event loop on its own X11 connection.

Comment: Is there any progress? I want to create a linux application similar to [mos](https://github.com/Caldis/Mos)

Answer (score 1):

> I'm writing a cross platform application, I want to be able to intercept keyboard input

If your application is a [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface) one, consider using a cross-platform framework such as [Qt](https://qt.io/) or [GTK](https://gtk.org/) (or [FLTK](https://www.fltk.org/), [FOX](http://www.fox-toolkit.org/), etc...). **If your application is command-line** (like e.g. [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) or [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) or [MongoDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB) are), **it might not even access the keyboard**, if used inside some [pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)), and you might also use cross-platform frameworks like [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/). If your software is started by [crontab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), it won't even have access to the keyboard, which might not even exist or be plugged in.

The same source code (for Qt or GTK or FLTK etc...) will work for Linux and for Windows.

BTW, many Linux computers (e.g. most web servers, or a [RasperryPi](https://raspberrypi.org/)) don't have any keyboard or mouse.

For more, read [Advanced Linux Programming](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) and [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html).

Read about [Xorg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.Org_Server) and [Wayland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_(display_server_protocol)).

> My application loads plugins, I am trying to stop the keystrokes from reaching the plugin's UI if it has focus.

[Plugins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)) on Linux are often implemented thru [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and [dlsym(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) as [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) shared objects, conventionally in files named `*.so` (so see [elf(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html)). Read the [Program Library HowTo](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/) and if you code in [C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) also the [C++ dlopen minihowto](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/C++-dlopen/). If you code in [Ocaml](https://ocaml.org/), use the [Dynlink](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.11/htmlman/libref/Dynlink.html) module. If you can code in [Common Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp) (e.g. using [SBCL](https://sbcl.org/)), you'll just use [`eval`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_eval.htm#eval). If you have to code in [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)), use some [class loader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader).

With `Xorg` (that is, [X11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System)) every keyboard event is generating some well defined message (some [XKeyEvent](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/events/keyboard-pointer/keyboard-pointer.html)) emitted - on a [tcp(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html) or [unix(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) socket- by the Xorg server to your [Xlib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xlib) client application.

On the client side (in your GUI application code), an [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) (around [poll(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) or [select(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html)...) is waiting for such messages. See also [time(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html).

On my [Debian](https://debian.org/) system (according to file `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and using [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)...) the `Xorg` server is accessing the keyboard (thru [udev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev)) as `/dev/input/event1` and [X11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) clients are [communicating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System_protocols_and_architecture) with the `Xorg` server.